# WSO2 API Manager authentication Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint error

Tags: sql-server, wso2, wso2-api-manager

We have implemented WSO2 API Manager (v1.10.0) in a distributed architecture as outlined in the online documentation [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/API+Manager+Clustering+Deployment+Patterns#APIManagerClusteringDeploymentPatterns-Single).

This consists of the following (on 5 separate servers):

- Gateway (x2)
- Publisher & Store (on a single server)
- Key Manager (x2)

These are wired-up to the 3 normal API Manager databases (Registry, User Manager & API Manager), which are on a SQL Server 2014 instance.

We are using the Key Managers for the authentication (login, forgotten password, etc.) of the website users, as well as for authenticating API calls.

However, when trying to log in to the site I'm seeing the following (Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint) error on the Key Manager:

> TID: [-1] [] [2016-10-06 00:36:47,842] ERROR
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.dao.TokenPersistenceTask} -  Error
>   occurred while persisting access token
>   :c5a0a11e63388dCHANGEDea34b0533445
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.dao.TokenPersistenceTask}
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.IdentityOAuth2Exception: Error when
>   storing the access token for consumer key :
>   fpA6AhOfbVCHANGEDgH0WzBDOga   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.dao.TokenMgtDAO.storeAccessToken(TokenMgtDAO.java:246)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.dao.TokenMgtDAO.persistAccessToken(TokenMgtDAO.java:284)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.dao.TokenPersistenceTask.run(TokenPersistenceTask.java:52)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Violation of UNIQUE
>   KEY constraint 'CON_APP_KEY'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object
>   'dbo.IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN'. The duplicate key value is (15,
>   williams.j2@CHANGED.org.uk, -1234, ,
>   APPLICATION_USER, 369db21a386ae4CHANGED0ff34d35708d, ACTIVE, NONE).   at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1515)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:404)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:350)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:180)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:155)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.execute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:332)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.dao.TokenMgtDAO.storeAccessToken(TokenMgtDAO.java:224)
>     ... 5 more

This is resulting in the following .NET error on the website:

[image: wso2 dotnet error]

I've tried Googling this, but cannot find an up-to-date answer.

I have not configured the Key Managers to have master and worked nodes (as outlined [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Separating+the+Worker+and+Manager+Nodes)) as the documentation seems to suggest that this isn't needed.

Any help would be much appreciated please!

Answer (score 1):

After some debugging found the issue! Before we put this config,

```
<JDBCPersistenceManager>
    <SessionDataPersist>
        <PoolSize>0</PoolSize>
    </SessionDataPersist>
</JDBCPersistenceManager>
```

APIM can save more than one ACTIVE OAUTH token to the IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN table for single token obtaining call.

When the token validation endpoint queries the tokens, only the last one is returned (Time based sorting and Limits are used). When that one is expired token validation mark it as inactive. But the previous one is kept as it is.

When the refresh token happens, it check whether the latest token is inactive. Since it is inactive, it issues a new token. But when the token endpoints tries to persist the token, there is another ACTIVE token. That caused this exception.

To sort this out we can run a update query on IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN table to mark all the ACTIVE tokens to INACTIVE.

```
update IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN set TOKEN_STATE="INACTIVE" where TOKEN_STATE="ACTIVE"
```

Then the old faulty tokens will be removed and server will start working fine!

Comment: Hi andunslg. Thanks for your answer. When do you run the `update` SQL command? Is that just a one-off task? If so, how do you prevent this problem from reoccurring?

Comment: The cause of this problem was initial run without adding         <PoolSize>0</PoolSize>. When it is 0, this will not occur.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still seeing the `CON_APP_KEY` unique key problem - even after setting `<PoolSize>0</PoolSize>`. This only happens when I refresh my application webpage after being away for a while.

Comment: I have the following in my *identity.xml*: 
 `<SessionDataPersist>
  <PoolSize>0</PoolSize>
             <Enable>true</Enable>
             <Temporary>false</Temporary>
             <SessionDataCleanUp>
                 <Enable>true</Enable>
                 <CleanUpTimeout>120</CleanUpTimeout>
                 <CleanUpPeriod>10</CleanUpPeriod>
             </SessionDataCleanUp>
             <OperationDataCleanUp>
                 <Enable>true</Enable>
                 <CleanUpPeriod>10</CleanUpPeriod>
             </OperationDataCleanUp>
 </SessionDataPersist>`

Comment: Find the entries which cause this SQL exception and remove all the active tokens under that.

Comment: I've removed all entries where `TOKEN_STATE='ACTIVE' and USER_TYPE='APPLICATION_USER'` from the `IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN` table and have also set `<PoolSize>0</PoolSize>` on both of my Key Manager servers, but am still seeing the occasional `Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'CON_APP_KEY'` error. Do I also need to set the `<PoolSize>0</PoolSize>` on the Store/Publisher? Is there something special I need to be doing in my application code?

Answer (score 1):

I use mysql and was facing the same problem. Changing the poolsize was also not a full solution. Then I noticed something strange about the idn_oauth2_access_token table. There is a column time_created, but the contents was not the time created. It was the last update timestamp. I read somewhere the systems orders on several columns among the time_created column. I inspected my sql script and saw that the database updated this column when a update was fired. I removed this rule and I have no more errors.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change below configuration (`<PoolSize>0</PoolSize>`) in `<APIM_HOME>/repository/conf/identity.xml`, and see?  By default, the PoolSize is set to 100.

```
<JDBCPersistenceManager>
    <SessionDataPersist>
        <PoolSize>0</PoolSize>
    </SessionDataPersist>
</JDBCPersistenceManager>
```

Hope this Will resolve your issue.

Reference: http://sanjeewamalalgoda.blogspot.com/2015/08/how-to-avoid-getting-incorrect-access.html

Comment: Hi @Bhathiya. Thanks for your answer. I did see the page that you're linking to. However, I discounted this as the version that I'm working with (v1.10.0 - rather than v1.9.0) doesn't have the `<APIM_HOME>/repository/conf/identity.xml` file and the `<APIM_HOME>/repository/conf/indentity/identity.xml` file that it does have does not have a `PoolSize` element within it. It does however have a `<SessionDataPersist><Enable>true</Enable>...</SessionDataPersist>` element (currently commented out). Should I uncomment that? If so, should its value be `true` or `false`?

Comment: I've just uncommented the `<SessionDataPersist>` element and tried setting `<Enable>true</Enable>` and then `<Enable>false</Enable>`. However,  I still had the same problem on both occasions. I'll experiment with running the cleanup first (by setting its value to 1) and then trying again with `<Enable>true</Enable>`

Comment: Yes, please try enabling it and set `<PoolSize>0</PoolSize>`.

Comment: I've implemented this, but am still seeing the same issue. I'm trying to pin down exactly when the new row is first added to the  `IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN` table in the API Manager database and under what conditions.

Comment: I am getting the same error in this version in our setup also!