# WSO2 APIM constraint violation CON_APP_KEY

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Sometimes, I encounter some problem to persist my new generated token in `MySQL database`.
This problem is similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39885646/wso2-api-manager-authentication-violation-of-unique-key-constraint-error) or [this](http://sanjeewamalalgoda.blogspot.com/2015/08/how-to-avoid-getting-incorrect-access.html).
Unfortunately even with `<PoolSize>0</PoolSize>` in identity.xml, I have sometimes the problem.
When it arrives, if I check the database, I notice the column `TIME_CREATED` is exactly equaled for the two last tokens.
 One is ACTIVE and the other INACTIVE. If I delete the active token everything work again. Occasionally, I can do it manually, but it isn't a real solution.
On the first post, I saw the response of @Sjaak but don't find MySQL script which updates the column `TIME_CREATED`

Thanks in advance for your help.